# Python CLI String Format into Columns

Tags: python, string

I'm developing a CLI app for connecting to WPE's API, meanwhile teaching myself some Python.   I hit the API and populate a local sqlite database, and then display the records from that database.

```
    # pull all our installs
    _ins = self._db.get_all_installs( )

    # fire up and index
    _idx = 1

    # fire up a dict object to hold the selectable item
    _selectable = []

    # loop over the results
    for _row in _ins:

        # gather up some info and through them into re-usable variables
        _wpe_id = _row[2]
        _name = _row[3]
        _environ = _row[4]

        # build a "menu" string
        _menu_str = "{}) {} - {}".format( _idx, _name, _environ )

        # add the items to a dict object
        _selectable.append( _wpe_id )

        # increment the index
        _idx += 1

        # display the item
        if _idx % 3 == 0:

            print("here, maybe??")

        # display the item
        print( _menu_str )
```

What I am struggling with in figuring out is how I can get this to break up the single-line single-row output.   Essentially what I would like to do is see this as a 3 column "menu".   How can I do this?

Right now, I have over 300 records, which outputs 1 line at a time.   Like:

```
1) Row 1
2) Row 2
3) Row 3
```

What I would like to do is like:

```
1) Row 1       2) Row 2       3) Row 3
```

etc...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `end` optional argument of `print` function:

```py
print(_menu_str, end='')
```

to remove the unwanted `\n`.

In your code, you would have something like this:

```py
if _idx % 3 == 2:
    print(_menu_str, end='')
else:
    print(_menu_str)
```

Comment: Didn't know we could do that LOL
Pretty close to what I need...    oddly though, `_idx % 3 ==0` doesnt seem to work right

Comment: teach me to post a comment before reloading an edittted answer... that definitely does the trick!  thanks a bunch

Comment: I changed the condition to `_idx % 3 == 2` to get the `\n` at the right moment :-).